# Strawberry plant or not? It has jagged toothed leaves. I didn't plant it

Tags: identification, strawberries

Is there a strawberry plant look like with jagged teeth?

Not sure where this plant came from, but here it is and the best I can make of it, it's a strawberry plant, but it looks strange. Does anyone know what this is? I live in Minnesota, zone 4. (maybe my little girl took a bite of a store-bought strawberry last year and threw it on the soil?)

[image: Strawberry plant that doesn't look like my others.]

Comment: I truely does not look like strawberry to me. But still I may be wrong.

Comment: Is this plant opposite leaved?  I am thinking off the cuff this might be a WILD GERANIUM.  5 lobes when a bit older?  White or pink flowers?  Could you crush a leaf and smell?  If Wild Geranium it will be strong, unmistakable.

Comment: @stormy I just crushed a leaf and smelled and there is no scent. No flowers (yet?).

Comment: Not a cultivated strawberry, possibly a wild one, though. It reminds me of a weed I know but can't place at the moment. If I remember the weed and it checks out, I'll post it as an answer. Almost certainly not a geranium.  EDIT - might be rough cinquefoil.

Comment: If I had to bet, I would probably agree with your assessment @Jurp. The leaves just seemed to be more jagged than the typical strawberry plants I've seen, so I I thought it might be something else. I'd love to try me some wild strawberries though!

Comment: There we go, Rough Cinquefoil!  Wild strawberrries that I've known wouldn't feed a sparrow! Looks like you have room for strawberries, the real ones...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like Rough Cinquefoil - Potentilla norvegica (also known as False Strawberry). Photo:https://www.ag.ndsu.edu/archive/entomology/ndsucpr/Years/2006/june/22/cinquefoil.jpg

It's an annual or biennial weed. If I'm correct, you'll see yellow, not white, flowers.

Comment: Yes, it is a Potentilla, Not sure it is P. novegica. Some P. have white flowers. In any case it is a weed.